# Reduce critical chain in Google Page Speed insights due to initial double step

Tags: pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

Why would this [site](http://autocosts.work/US) that I manage have a double step in chain on the landing page, according to Google Page Speed?

[image]

I'm using `handlerbars` and on the `main.hbs`, I have something like

```
<head>
  ...
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/mergedInit.css" media="screen" />
  ...
</head>
<body>
..
..
    <script src="/client/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/client/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

It has to do with any HTTP redirect? Where that initial double step might come from?

Comment: Likely happening because of HTTP to HTTPS redirect. If the test is run on the HTTP version ( https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http://autocosts.work/US ) the double step issue is reported by Google PageSpeed Insights but if the test is run on the HTTPS version ( https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https://autocosts.work/US ) there are no problems

Comment: @PrayagVerma thanks a lot, do kindly, if you want, put that as an answer such that I can assigned it as the solution. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue occurs because the test is run on the HTTP version of the website which gets automatically redirected to the HTTPS

Running the PageSpeed Insights tool directly on the HTTPS version of the website (https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https://autocosts.work/US) resolves the problem